# Vue.js использование refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

Всем привет ,как будет выглядеть если явную работу с DOM тут заменить на refs? У меня что-то не выходит так заменить

```
const holder = document.querySelector('.item');
      holder.ondragover = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        holder.classList.add('holder--dragover');
        return false
      };
      holder.ondragleave = holder.ondragend = holder.ondrop = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        holder.classList.remove('holder--dragover');
        return false
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставите элементу ref:

```
<div ref="holder" class="item"></div>
```

Если такой элемент на странице будет один, то получить можно через

```
this.$refs.holder
```

Если много, то:

```
this.$refs.holder[<индекс элемента>]
```

У вас по коду скорее всего один элемент, вот так будет выглядеть код:

```
const holder = this.refs.holder;

holder.ondragover = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  holder.classList.add('holder--dragover');
  return false
};
holder.ondragleave = holder.ondragend = holder.ondrop = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  holder.classList.remove('holder--dragover');
  return false
};
```

Подробнее [ТУТ](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).